# Creating a dictionary to count the number of occurrences of Sequence IDs

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, counting

I'm trying to write a function to count the number of each sequence ID that occurs in this file (it's a sample blast file)

[image]

The picture above is the input file I'm dealing with.

```
def count_seq(input):
    dic1={}
    count=0
    for line in input:
        if line.startswith('#'):
        continue
    if line.find('hits found'):
        line=line.split('\t')
        if line[1] in dic1:
            dic1[line]+=1
        else:
            dic1[line]=1
return dic1
```

Above is my code which when called just returns empty brackets {}

So I'm trying to count how many times each of the sequence IDs (second element of last 13 lines) occur eg: FO203510.1 occurs 4 times.

Any help would be appreciated immensely, thanks!

Comment: Text is much preferred over images here. People like to copy/paste and test their solutions on your data.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for letting me know, I didn't think of that and didn't realise it'd be a problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're after:

```
def count_seq(input_file):
    dic1={}
    with open(input_file, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line.startswith('#'):
                line = line.split()
                seq_id = line[1]
                if not seq_id in dic1:
                    dic1[seq_id] = 1
                else:
                    dic1[seq_id] += 1

    return dic1

print(count_seq("blast_file"))
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do , thanks! Still getting my head around loops and dictionaries!

Answer (score 2):

This is a fitting case for **collections.defaultdict**. Let `f` be the file object. Assuming the sequences are in the second column, it's only a few lines of code as shown.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
seqs = (line.split()[1] for line in f if not line.strip().startswith("#"))
for seq in seqs:
    d[seq] += 1
```

See if it works!